# Alteration vs Light armor for roleplaying purposes

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am planning to get into the Thieves Guild and Dark Brotherhood questlines. My character is a sort of a Battlemage with Heavy Armor, Destruction, One Handed, Illusion, Smithing and Enchanting focus. As of yet, I have maxed Sneak. I am currently at level 62, have about 3 spare perk points and a perspective to grow to about level 70.

I was wondering, whether I should pick up Light Armor or Alteration, as a Thief or Assassin in full Daedric armor is a bit silly. You know - you can't sneak in them, even if the game thinks you can.

So basically I can't decide which skill to pick. I have invested in Silent Casting, so as to utilize both Spells and Weapons in an effort to make my character a sort of magical assassin. Alteration seems to have cooler perks and isn't as redundant as Light Armor to my hero, yet I still can't decide whether it's a viable choice for a Thief. You know - evil Dark Brotherhood killer can use it, but Thieves guild members aren't exactly known for their skill in magic.

Another point is, that I don't have that many perks left to acquire and I have been considering that I could also learn Archery. In this regard Light Armor seems better, as it doesn't require such a heavy perk investment.

So what do you think is more appropriate?

Comment: Please [read the FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq). This is an opinion question, and fits a discussion board / forum better than a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you save your game and then spend your perks on different trees to see what combination works better for you.

There is no point going all that way as a battlemage to start learning archery now (unless your at a high archery level already)
Using silent magic for the dark brotherhood will be dam good work, and for the thieves guild, you wont really be fighting at all (opinion) due to stealing most of the time.

But it's rightfully your choice in the end, The light Armour tree works very well for almost all others, with better perks going up to the weightlessness of it eventually,

Now, choosing alteration, whether your a thief or not doesn't really matter, or maybe it does to you, But you initially need to activate that, whereas the Armour you do not.

but just look at the tree, at the perks, and have a hard think, think about everything you do, how it will help in any and all situations, think about light Armour too, then you will finally see which one will be worth it more.

That's what helps me, thinking far in advance and how i will use those perks,

I hope any of this helps you out friend

Rob